Handling old legacy message with MassTransit
I have an existing email service implementation that listens on an Azure Service Bus and uses the native library Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.
I need now to add a separate processing for other kind of email and I would like to handle the message with MassTransit as I've done for other portion of the infrastructure we have.
The messages I'm sending in the old way are really simple as payload, something as:
{
    "FromEmail": "aaa@domain.com",
    "ToEmail": "abc@thedomain.com.com",
    "BCcEmail": null,
    "Subject": "Error",
    "Body": null,
    "IsBodyHtml": true,
    "TemplateId": "940108",
    "Variables": {
        "EmailType": "Error Notification",
        "Subject": "Error",
        "Message": "The signature for the webhook is not present in the Stripe-Signature header."
    }

I was wondering if I could update both the endpoints if it's possible with MassTransit for a certain period (until we release all the services with MassTransit) to have the library check if it's a MT message and process the new way otherwise go in legacy mode


You can consume raw JSON: https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/serialization#raw-json

Thanks a lot, and is there a way to handle both? So if message is 'old' threat as raw otherwise use Masstransit consumer?
